# Diferencia entre función de declaración y de expresión

Tags: javascript

empece a hacer un curso de javascript en donde nos enseñaron dos tipos de funciones: de declaración y de expresión. No logro entender bien en que se diferencian estos dos tipos ya que me habían dicho que uno devuelve un valor inmediato y otro no.
Si alguien pudiese darme un ejemplo sencillo y claro de la diferencia con una mínima explicación se los agradecería.

Expresión:

```
var foo = function() { return 5; }
```

Declaración:

```
function foo() { return 5; }
```

Desde ya gracias!

Comment: coloca un ejemplo de ambas para complementar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: gracias ya lo actualice!

Comment: te sigo actualizando la respuesta revisala de nuevo por favor+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
/*expresiones de funciones*/
let saludo = function(){
  return "saludo"
}
console.log(saludo())

/*definición de una función*/
function adios(){
  return "adios"
}
console.log(adios())

/*Como puedes notar para ambos casos se tiene que
hacer la invocación o del nombre de la función o del
nombre de la variable que la contiene.

Por ejemplo en el primer caso se esta usando una función
anónima que esta vinculada a una variable que para este ejemplo
se llama saludo y es la misma variable que después en el console.log se imprime.

En el segundo caso no es una función anónima puesto que fue nombrada
como adios y con ese mismo nombre es invocada en el segundo console.log*/
```

Como puedes notar para ambos casos se tiene que
hacer la invocación o del nombre de la función o del
nombre de la variable que la contiene.

Por ejemplo en el primer caso se esta usando una función
anónima que esta vinculada a una variable que para este ejemplo
se llama saludo y es la misma variable que después en el console.log se imprime.

En el segundo caso no es una función anónima puesto que fue nombrada
como adios y con ese mismo nombre es invocada en el segundo console.log

> Las funciones de tipo expresión van a ser útiles cuando sean pasadas
>   como argumento de una función, gracias al nombre de la variable que
>   contiene la función anónima en su interior

**FUNCIÓN POR EXPRESIÓN**

Otra diferencia es que por ejemplo cuando haces una función por expresión, del modo siguiente

```js
console.log(suma(2, 3))
    
    var suma = function(x,y) {
       return x + y;
    };
```

> va a devolver error, por que la función esta asignada a una variable
>   que justo así como esta el ejemplo aún no ha sido definida

**FUNCIÓN POR DECLARACIÓN O DEFINICIÓN**

Pero ahora fijate que si hago una función por declaración del modo siguiente

```js
 console.log(suma(2, 3))
    
    function suma(x,y) {
       return x + y;
    };
```

> Me va a imprimir el resultado y no me va a marcar error por que la
>   función esta disponible para todo el programa y no depende de que una
>   variable que la contenga ya haya sido definida

A partir de ES6, las arrow functions o funciones de tipo flecha tienen la característica de ser declaradas como funciones por expresión, mira el ejemplo

```js
let potencia = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a ** b)
}

potencia(2, 3)
```